# Having an Android service as both background and foreground service

Tags: android, service, foreground

I've read that I should call

```
startForegroundService(intent)
```

if I want to properly start a service that can run as a foreground service. But how should I think if I want it to start without it being a foreground service but potentially becoming one later on? Some info on how we have it right now:

We have an App which uses a service for many tasks. It performs all of these task when the user interacts with the app in the foreground but depending on if the user has enabled a certain feature we want to keep performing these tasks in the background. So when the app is launched (and obviously is in foreground) we start the service using

```
startService(intent);
```

When the app transitions into background we check whether the feature is enabled, and if so, run `startForeground(id, notificiation);` which effectively adds the non-removable notification out in the OS and the service keeps on running. When the app goes back into foreground we call `stopForeground(true)`. If the feature isn't enabled the service will never be set as a foreground service and we won't try to perform these tasks in the background.

**So my question is:** Is this sufficient to get the "full foreground service performance"? Or am I losing something by not calling `startForegroundService(intent)`? My impression is that we actually do have a fully working foreground service but I'm getting confused when I read statements that `foreground services must be started using startForegroundService(intent)` which we're not doing. If we really **need** to use `startForegroundService(intent)`, the only solution I can think of would be to initially start a normal instance of the service and when the app enters background we start a new one using `startForegroundService(intent)`. But do we need to do this or is running `startForegund(id, notification)` on a service started using `startService(intent)` sufficient to achieve a foreground service?

**NOTE:** One difference I find is that if the application itself is in background when start the service I then need `startForegroundService(intent)` for API >= 26. In our case we always start the service when the app is in foreground. I do however recall some instances where I've seen the exception thrown when we try to start the service using `startService(intent)`, somehow the app (very very rarely) still think it's in background (perhaps something from the OS comes up just when app is launched). So if I catch when that happens I could run `startForegroundService(intent)` to start the service. But is it possible to run `stopForeground(true)` on that service when the app comes back into foreground? Or is it bound to be a foreground service forever since we started it that way?

Comment: I think your answer is [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#atap). they added a lot of restriction in Android O. the only way to running long live services is to start the in the foreground, otherwise, os kill them or throw an Exception

Comment: Yes, but we are starting the background service with `startService(intent)` when the app is in foreground which is still allowed. And we then set it to foreground using `startForeground(id, notification)` when the app enters background. So that doesn't really answer any of the questions. If the app is in foreground and I run `startService(intent)` followed by `startForeground(id, notification)`, will that be **any** different from running `startForegroundService(intent)` followed by `startForeground(id, notification)`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't have to call `startForegroundService` and `startService` is sufficient:

> If your service is started (running through Context#startService(Intent)), **then also make this service run in the foreground**, supplying the ongoing notification to be shown to the user while in this state. By default started services are background, meaning that their process won't be given foreground CPU scheduling (unless something else in that process is foreground) and, if the system needs to kill them to reclaim more memory (such as to display a large page in a web browser), they can be killed without too much harm. You use startForeground(int, Notification) if killing your service would be disruptive to the user, such as if your service is performing background music playback, so the user would notice if their music stopped playing.

From [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

Answer (score 0):

I read your question multiple time and I think (hopefully) the answer to your question is :

According to the official document of Android 8.0 Background Execution Limits:

> Android 8.0 introduces the new method startForegroundService() to
>   start a new service in the foreground. After the system has created
>   the service, the app has five seconds to call the service's
>   startForeground() method to show the new service's user-visible
>   notification. If the app does not call startForeground() within the
>   time limit, the system stops the service and declares the app to be
>   ANR.

So, make sure you have started ongoing notification by calling startForeground (int id, Notification notification) in the onCreate() method of your service.

Note: Apps targeting API Build.VERSION_CODES.P or later must request the permission Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE in order to use this API.

And there is great medium article posted by [Maciej Witowski](https://proandroiddev.com/@maciejwitowski) that help you understand how really new services API works :
https://proandroiddev.com/pitfalls-of-a-foreground-service-lifecycle-59f014c6a125

Comment: Thanks for the reply but if I rephrase. From Android 8 and onward we **must** use `startForegroundService()` and then call `startForeground()` quick enough if we want to start a foreground service **when app is in background**. However, if the application itself is in foreground we can still use `startService()` followed by `startForeground()` in order to start a foreground service. In my case I start in when the app is in foreground. And then, does it make any difference which way I do it?

Comment: Some articles I read specify "you cannot use startService() anymore" but the docs simply state `Unlike the ordinary startService(android.content.Intent), this method can be used at any time, regardless of whether the app hosting the service is in a foreground state.`